# TaskDialog not working on (or replacement for) Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, taskdialog

We have an older WPF application that makes use of the "Windows API Code Pack" in order to show a Task Dialog (something that was introduced back in Vista but worked all the way through Windows 8).

I'm now trying to run the project on Windows 10, and when I try to show the Task Dialog, I get the following exception:

> **System.AccessViolationException**: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>   at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.TaskDialogNativeMethods.TaskDialogIndirect (TaskDialogConfiguration taskConfig, Int32& button, Int32& radioButton, Boolean& verificationFlagChecked)
>     at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.NativeTaskDialog.NativeShow()
>     at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.TaskDialog.ShowCore()

Are these APIs no longer available in Windows 10?

Is there a replacement with similar functionality that is available in Windows 10 without writing a custom dialog?

Edit: I got it to run (sheer luck I guess? I didn't change any code) and the dialog popped up like this:

[image: Win10 Task Dialog]

There should be 3 buttons, and definitely no Chinese characters, so I would agree with the exception that there is definitely some memory issue going on here. Any ideas?

Comment: The "chinese" characters may hint that there is a problem with string encodings, either in your code or in the library.

Comment: @Alejandro Since I have not worked on this application recently, and it used to work a few years ago, I would bet there's an issue in the library (which hasn't been updated in many years). :) My question still stands - **what alternatives do we have for Windows 10 to achieve this functionality?**

Comment: [The last commin on their GitHub page is from 2016](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/commits/master), is that library what you're talking about?

Comment: @Alejandro Yes that is the one I am using which is not working for my WPF .NET 4.5 project anymore.

Comment: Do you have some sample code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Task Dialog is still supported in Windows 10, but the problem is likely this issue in the library that you seem to be using: https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/issues/3

As noted in the issue description, it can cause the `AccessViolationException` (and probably the incorrect characters) on **64-bit** Windows. You can fix it by applying the changes from the referenced pull request.

<sup>Note: There is a request to include an official Task Dialog implementation in future .NET Core versions now that WinForms is open source: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/146</sup>